# suiteCRM email field doesn't appear in chrome

Tags: crm, sugarcrm, suitecrm

In a suiteCRM system freshly installed the email address field doesn't appear when creating a new contact or account. 
This problem doesn't occur in FireFox , but it appears in chrome and Safari!

Comment: Can you try editing the view in studio? Does this make any difference?

Comment: makes no difference !

Comment: You may get more responses on the [SuiteCRM support forums](http://suitecrm.co.uk/index.php?option=com_kunena&view=category&Itemid=1137&layout=list)

Answer (score 1):

Those fields are dinamically added by js, which also is activated when you press the plus button to add a new address. Open you chrome Console and try to see if you get any error. Also, try a quick repair and rebuild in Admin panel.